# Linear regression issue with categorical variables

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I've built a linear regression model predicting recidivism among convicts based on the COMPAS dataset.
I've some issues regarding the categorical variables, specifically the gender variable.
This was transformed to dummy variables and dropping one of the two binary variables to prevent collinearity.
However it seems after training the model the female gender gets a higher recidivism score than the male gender.
It looks like this is not correct, since the male offenders have a higher score on the independent variables than females.
Also the target variable (recidivism score) is lower in the female category than the male.
I would expect that females would have a lower predicted score.
I get the feeling that there's something wrong with the model.
Can someone please help me out?
See below the dataset and code:

subset of the data after dummy transformation and data cleansing:

```py
age;priors_count;juv_fel_count;sex_Male;race_Caucasian;race_Asian;race_Hispanic;race_NativeAmerican;race_Other;v_decile_score;event;is_recid;decile_score
69;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;1
69;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;1
34;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;3
24;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;1;4
24;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;1;4
24;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;1;4
24;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;1;4
24;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;1;4
41;14;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;1;6
41;14;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;1;6
43;3;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;3;0;0;4
43;3;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;3;0;0;4

#model
X = df[[
            'age'
            ,'priors_count'
            ,'juv_fel_count'
            ,'sex_Male'
            ,'race_Caucasian'
            ,'race_Asian'
            ,'race_Hispanic'
            ,'race_Native American'
            ,'race_Other'
            ,'v_decile_score'
            ,'event'
            ,'is_recid'
        ]] 
Y = df['decile_score']

# with sklearn
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, Y)

print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

# prediction with sklearn
New_Age = 18
New_Priors_Count = 0
New_Juvenile_Count = 0
New_Sex_Male = 0

#Race Variables
# 0 in all the below means TRUE for Afro-American Race
New_Race_Caucasian = 0
New_Race_Asian = 0
New_Race_Hispanic = 0
New_Race_Native_American = 0
New_Race_Other = 0

#Violence & Events
New_Violent_Score = 0
New_Event_In_Custody = 0
New_Is_Recid = 0

print ('Recividism Score: \n', 
       regr.predict(
       [[
                 New_Age
               , New_Priors_Count
               , New_Juvenile_Count
               , New_Sex_Male
               , New_Race_Caucasian
               , New_Race_Asian
               , New_Race_Hispanic
               , New_Race_Native_American
               , New_Race_Other
               , New_Violent_Score
               , New_Event_In_Custody
               , New_Is_Recid
               # , New_Days_In_Jail
        ]]
     ))

# with statsmodels
X = sm.add_constant(X) # adding a constant
 
model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X) 
 
print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)
```

Comment: It may well be that females have a lower recidivism score than males on average, and yet in the context of the full model, females have a higher recidivism score than males, **given equal values of all the other variables**. To give a simplified example, if you compare females and males who all have 10 prior convictions, the females may have a higher recidivism rate. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox

Comment: Have you experimented without dropping one of the values of the dummy variable ?